# Nextjs Container unable to connect to PostgresQL server

Tags: postgresql, docker, next.js, docker-compose, containers

I was creating a portfolio website powered by nextjs and postgreSQL. I have been trying to troubleshoot the connection by logging results to a console using a db.js file but it refuses to connect. My adminer can connect but not the nextjs app.

```
//docker-compose.yml
services:
    portfolio:
        build: .
        restart: always
        image: nextjs
        ports:
            -   3000:3000
        depends_on:
            -   db
        environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://dayngerous:12dayN34@127.0.0.1:5432/pg-portfolio
        networks:
            -   portfolio-network
        volumes:
            -    type: bind
                 source: ./src/pages
                 target: /app/src/pages
            -    type: bind
                 source: ./src/api
                 target: /app/src/api

    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: pg-portfolio
        ports:
            -    5432:5432
        volumes:
            -    pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata
        networks:
       - portfolio-network

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - portfolio-network

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

networks:
  portfolio-network:
```

And this

```
\\db.js
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client(
  "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/pg-portfolio"
);

client.connect();

client.query("SELECT * from user_profile", (err, res) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(res.rows);
  } else {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  client.end;
});
```

I have tried to console log results from my database but to no avail. I have also tried running a bash shell from the next js container and it did not work.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you are using localhost to connect to postgres. Your docker service file has a name `db` , which means docker will create an internal DNS for you by name `db` and this will direct you to the postgres container. You have to change your connection string to `postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/pg-portfolio`.  This is the first step. Next you have to modify the `pg_hba` config file of your postgres container to enable connections to various users and various DBs. Try the first change and let me know if it works. Also ensure to provide correct username and pwd.